# How to set background color of tableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have tried all the way but could not succeed to set backgroundColor of TableView.
setting `tableView.backgroundColor` and/or `cell.backgroundColor` to `clearColor` didn't work when the parent view controller was `UIViewContoller`.

My nib file structure is

```
FileOwner
View
UITableView
```

(Note: i set the TableView to groupedTable section)

First attempt, I created the `UIView` in the code `viewDidLoad`

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 300)] autorelease;
[view setBackgroundColor:UIColor blueColor]; // color it just to see if it is created at the right place
[self.tableView sendSubViewToBack:view];
```

It works but it hides the content of cell. I am able to see the content of header but not cell content. (But when i change the co-ordinate of view(0,150,160,300) then i am able to see the cell's content but then it loose the backgroundColor of tableview.

Second attempt,
I created the imageView

```
View
ImageView
UITableView
```

and set the `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` but did not work.

I googled but did not the peaceful answer.

Comment: Is there an answer for this question?

Answer (score 5):

A UITableView with the grouped style uses a background view.  To get rid of the background view and let the background color show, try either of the following:

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

After that, you should be able to set the background color normally:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

BTW, only a view can be the parent/superview of another view, and a view controller is not a view.

Comment: Thanks drawonward, it works. it tool several hour for me and googled a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This has always worked for me:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[parentView addSubview:tableView];
```

Make sure that the tableView is not nil, not hidden, has the correct frame, and that it has been added to the correct parent view.

Answer (score 3):

Swift Version

```
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```